# How to enable all disabled when print

Tags: javascript, css

I have client print button. And I can hide something when print using

```
@media print
      {
        .NonPrintable {display:none;}
      }
```

But I also have some disabled elements, when print out, it shows gray. I wanna enable those elements when print, so it will look nice. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the disabled state via CSS, but you *can* change its appearance.

You can target any attribute in CSS using the form:

```
<selector>[attr="value"] {
    /* Styles here */
}
```

So for your case, you could do something like:

```
selector[disabled="disabled"] {
    /* Styles here */
}
```

See http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/ for a discussion on targeting attributes, and see http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/RYpcz/ as an example of targeting the "disabled" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe do some javascript and enable them before printing?
[onbeforeprint](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeprint.asp)